# Background color change makes all elements disappear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to change the background color of the entire screen. So I have tried to add this code `UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red`. It changes the background color but sadly it makes everything else disappear. So if someone let me know what I did wrong I would be very happy about what.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("hello")
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

[image: Simulator and Xcode Preview/Canvas]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about UIKIt and UIView. You just need a ZStack:

```
struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text("hello")
        }   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```